# Are these 3 summation expressions equivalent?

Tags: summation

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(i)+k = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\{f(i)+k\} = k+\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(i) $$

I'm more confused about the working of expression: 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\{f(i)+k\}$$

Are all the 3 expressions equivalent?

Comment: In the first expression put the parentheses to make it more easily understandable: is it $$\sum_{i=1}^n f(i)+k = \sum_{i=1}^n (f(i)+k)? $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. But these are:$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(i)+nk = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\{f(i)+k\} = nk+\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(i) $$

If you're summing a constant $n$ times, you need to multiply it by $n$ if you want to bring it outside the summation

Comment: None of the above expressions in the question are equivalent?

Comment: @Sidsec9 No, because there is no $n$ in front of $k$. I mean you can try it yourself, take $f(i) = i$, $n=2$, $k=3$ and see if the results are the same

Answer (score 1):

The second and third are different.  The second one is 
$$\{f(1)+k\}+\{f(2)+k\}+\{f(3)+k\}+...$$ which contains $n$ lots of $k$, so it equals $kn+\sum_{i=1}^nf(i)$.
The first one is ambiguous; I am not certain whether the sum includes $k$ within its scope, so it is equal to either the second or third one.

Comment: I understand what you do there, but I think it's better to avoid writing a sum of sets: $\{a\}+\{b\}$ is neither $a+b$ nor $\{a+b\}$ (though there are of course canonical bijections between these objects)